# SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: ~@henris/utils

Tags: reactjs, import, sass

I get the following error when I try to import my sass file in my ReactApp:
import './styles/base.scss'
I double checked all paths and filenames but that's not the issue.

Who knows what to do?

```
./src/styles/base.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/styles/base.scss)

        on line 1 of node_modules/test-off/dist/assets/scss/functions/_index.scss
        from line 1 of node_modules/test-off/dist/assets/scss/base.scss
        from line 1 of /Users/John/MyAPP/NextBest/src/styles/base.scss
>> @import '~@henris/utils';
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the @henris/utils package solved my problem